# how to group rows from a pandas data frame that match multiple date-time conditions

Tags: pandas

I used the code below to create the following data frame:

> df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[['2024-02-22 03:42:06.065'],['2024-02-22
> 03:47:29.152'], ['2024-02-21 19:37:05.142'], ['2024-02-21
> 19:40:13.851'], ['2024-02-21 19:41:21.388'], ['2024-02-21
> 19:47:29.828'], ['2024-02-21 19:48:10.684'],['2024-02-22
> 02:59:36.786']]})

| id | Date |
| --- | --- |
| AB1234 | [2024-02-22 03:42:06.065] |
| AB1234 | [2024-02-22 03:46:29.152] |
| CD3456 | [2024-02-21 19:37:05.142] |
| CD3456 | [2024-02-21 19:40:13.851] |
| CD3456 | [2024-02-21 19:41:21.388] |
| GH3447 | [2024-02-21 19:47:29.828] |
| GH3447 | [2024-02-21 19:48:10.684] |
| GH3447 | [2024-02-22 02:59:36.786] |

I need to check if the difference between the dates in 2 (or more) consecutive rows that belong to the same id is <= 5 minutes. (So, if 4 rows belong to the same id, we compare that the diff between row1 and row2, between row2 and row3, and row3 and row4 are <=5 minutes). If yes, group those rows together (below the 'count' column). If not, put them in a different group (as shown in the 'count' column). The purpose is to check if the difference between two consecutive dates that belong to the same id is <= 5 minutes. So, the output should be something like the below:

| id | Date | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB1234 | [2024-02-22 03:42:06.065] | 1 |
| AB1234 | [2024-02-22 03:46:29.152] | 1 |
| CD3456 | [2024-02-21 19:37:05.142] | 2 |
| CD3456 | [2024-02-21 19:40:13.851] | 2 |
| CD3456 | [2024-02-21 19:41:21.388] | 2 |
| GH3447 | [2024-02-21 19:47:29.828] | 3 |
| GH3447 | [2024-02-21 19:48:10.684] | 3 |
| GH3447 | [2024-02-22 02:59:36.786] | 4 |

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Let's start by defining the data type of your date column (which needs to have the list from each row removed)

```py
df.date = df.date.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df.date = df.date.astype("datetime64[ns]")
```

which gives us

```
        id                     date
0   AB1234  2024-02-22 03:42:06.065
1   AB1234  2024-02-22 03:46:29.152
2   CD3456  2024-02-21 19:37:05.142
3   CD3456  2024-02-21 19:40:13.851
4   CD3456  2024-02-21 19:41:21.388
```

We then use three key methods, `df.diff`, `df.apply`, and `df.groupby` to complete this.

I started by creating a function to run through apply, which either returns the current group (`cnt`) or creates a new group and updates `cnt`. Note if your python is <3.8, you cannot use the `:=` operator, instead you can use a standard variable update (see below)

```
def is_group(df):
    global cnt
    if df["diff"] or not (pd.isna(df["cnt"])):
        return cnt
    else:
    # For Python >=3.8
        return (cnt := cnt + 1)
    # For Python <3.8
        cnt += 1
        return cnt
```

Then apply this to the grouped dataframes, using `diff` and the 5 minutes condition to create a mask for where to start groups

```
cnt = 0
for g, gdf in df.groupby("id"):
    cnt += 1
    gdf["diff"] = gdf.date.diff() <= pd.Timedelta("5 minutes")
    gdf["cnt"] = [cnt] + [None] * (len(gdf) - 1)
    gdf["cnt"] = gdf.apply(is_group, axis=1)
    for idx in gdf.index:
        df.at[idx, "cnt"] = gdf.at[idx, "cnt"]
```

This gave me

```
        id                     date cnt
0   AB1234  2024-02-22 03:42:06.065 1.0
1   AB1234  2024-02-22 03:46:29.152 1.0
2   CD3456  2024-02-21 19:37:05.142 2.0
3   CD3456  2024-02-21 19:40:13.851 2.0
4   CD3456  2024-02-21 19:41:21.388 2.0
5   GH3447  2024-02-21 19:47:29.828 3.0
6   GH3447  2024-02-21 19:48:10.684 3.0
7   GH3447  2024-02-22 02:59:36.786 4.0
```

I tried doing this through a single apply, but couldn't achieve the updating on groups being further than 5 minutes apart.

***OLD ANSWER***

If you define the date column as a datetime object, which you can do as:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'date':[
            '2024-02-22 03:42:06.065',
            '2024-02-22 03:47:29.152', 
            '2024-02-21 19:37:05.142', 
            '2024-02-21 19:40:13.851', 
            '2024-02-21 19:41:21.388', 
            '2024-02-21 19:47:29.828', 
            '2024-02-21 19:48:10.684',
            '2024-02-22 02:59:36.786'
        ]
    },
    dtype="datetime64[ns]"
)
```

You can iterate over the rows to check which rows fit the criteria as below, assuming I understand your logic of any row within 5 minutes of the given row?

```py
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    df.at[idx, 'count'] = \
        df.loc[abs(df.date - row.date) <= pd.Timedelta("5 minutes"), :] \
            .count() \
                .iloc[1]
```

For each row, you get all rows (`df.iterrows`) within 5 minutes (`abs(df.date - row.date) <= pd.Timedelta("5 minutes")`) for that row compared to all other rows in the dataframe, then take the count which summarises the dataframe to count how many values in each column, and then just simplify to a single value (`iloc[1]`) instead of a whole dataframe. This is updated at the row index in the `count` column (`df.at[idx, 'count']`)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Just a little correction in the logic: for each row, I just want to check if the difference between the current row and the following row is <=5 minutes or not. If yes, group them together (e.g. with the same number in the "sum" column) and if not, put them in different group (e.g., with a different number in the 'sum' column), as I've shown in my output example. Could you please paste the updated code for this? Thanks again.

Comment: If there was 3 rows with say the times (same date) 3:10 3:15 3:20, how would that logic work? 3:10 groups to just 3:15, but 3:15 is grouped by 3:10 but then would include 3:20? Also, the `sum` column is not actually a sum or count? It's just say a group ID for want of a different word?

Comment: I apologize for unclear exp. I updated the examples above.  I need to check if the difference between the dates in 2 (or more) consecutive rows that belong to the same id is <= 5 minutes. (So, if 4 rows belong to the same id, we compare that the diff between row1 and row2, between row2 and row3, and row3 and row4 are <=5 minutes). If yes, group those rows together (below the 'count' column). If not, put them in a different group (as shown in the 'count' column). Purpose is to check if the diff between two or more consecutive dates that belong to the same id is <= 5 minutes.

Comment: I've updated my answer as per your explanation

Comment: Thanks! It worked.